# Getting a raspberry pi online

Tags: pi-3, wireless

Okay so I have my Raspberry pi and I have apache2 running on it. I would like have a domain connected to my raspberry pi. I have the static ip for the raspberry pi(192.168.1.95), but i also have my public ip(xxx.xxx.xx.xxx). When i login to my router(Pace model 5268AC  ISP: U-verse) I go to the firewall tab and select the configuration and I tried to forward a port so i can connect to it but im not sure. Im sort of lost. I just want to be able to go to a domain and see my webpage. Thanks for the help in advance!!

Edit: My goal is to make the webpage a login page and if you have the credentials then you can view my plex server running on my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1):

In your router you need to forward port 80 (or it might be labelled as the HTTP service) to your Pis static ip address (192.168.1.95).

Then OUTSIDE of your home network (your your mobile, with wifi disabled) browse to the public ip address and see if it works. (You need to be outside your home network as your router is unlikely to do 'hairpinning')

You also need to make sure that apache is listening on the private ip address (not just localhost)

Comment: Okay I have it working on my phone through my carrier. How would i assign my ip to a domain. On namecheap I created an A record that has the '@' host and my public ip.

Comment: Your ISP almost certainly does not provide a static IP for your router; it changes periodically but probably at least every 24 hours, so you are out of luck.  You can use a "no-ip" service, but this won't be compatible with the namecheap domain you bought.  You could inquire with your ISP about what a static IP costs; here it requires you switch to a business account, which is not necessarily more than a home account, but the static IP is then an extra $20/month.

Comment: If you already have a static IP set up, "How would i assign my ip to a domain" is off-topic here as it has nothing to do with the pi.  You can research this online and/or try asking on our larger sibling site [Super User](http://superuser.com/) (although they will likely close it quickly as a duplicate since no doubt this has already been asked thousands of times, which means at least you will get an answer, or you could save yourself the hassle and just use the search there).  You should also check namecheap's help/documentation, since you probably have to go through them.

Comment: I think you were trying to use @ as the label in the DNS A record, and that's not a valid character...  Try pi or something else, making the URL you need to browse to pi.yourdomain.com